# Magento 1.9 : getSkinUrl() displaying content as HTTP instead of HTTPS. How do I fix this?

Tags: magento-1.9, frontend, ssl, https, skin

I'm trying to get my site over to https.

But, i'm getting mixed content errors. I looked into one of them and it is an image, and that image is being used like this:

```
<img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/mgt_lazy_image_loader/loader.gif'); ?>"
```

How do I fix this? Shouldn't this be using my Secure Base Skin URL field from inside the Admin?

Comment: Were you able to solve your issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can get HTTPS urls by adding secure param as following ;

```
<img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/mgt_lazy_image_loader/loader.gif', array('_secure'=>true)); ?>"
```